# iOS Swift: Generic array cast to array of subclass

Tags: ios, swift, generics, casting

This one has been bugging me for a while now. I'm not sure if I'm missing something, but shouldn't this work?

```
protocol IDIdentifiable { }

class A : IDIdentifiable {
    let id : Int
    init(id: Int) { self.id = id }
}

class B : IDIdentifiable {
    let id : Int
    init(id: Int) { self.id = id }
}

func findObjectById<T: IDIdentifiable>(objects: [T], id: Int) -> T {
    if let casted = objects as? [A] {
        return casted.filter{ $0.id == id }[0]
    }
}
```

The error happens when casting the objects parameter to an array of A-objects. The error says `'A' is not a subtype of 'T'`, which is obviously not the case.

It's really annoying since I would like to have a generic method that can handle arrays of objects of multiple classes the same way. I tried first without creating an extra protocol like IDIdentifiable, using switch-statements, but none of these approaches worked.

I'm happy for any suggestions!

Comment: Isn't this the same as my question here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself

Comment: Stop saying "didn't work". That is meaningless. You have fixed the question by explaining that the issue is a compile error. That is what I was after.

Comment: Very similar indeed. Strange nonetheless.

Comment: 'A' is not a subtype of 'IDIdentifiable' Is correct. But IDIdentifiable Is a subtype of A. You can up-cast arrays but not downcast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you declare the protocol to require a variable `id` you don't need to cast the type in the generic method.

```
protocol IDIdentifiable {
  var id : Int { get set }
}

class A : IDIdentifiable {
  var id : Int
  init(id: Int) { self.id = id }
}

class B : IDIdentifiable {
  var id : Int
  init(id: Int) { self.id = id }
}

func findObjectById<T: IDIdentifiable>(objects: [T], id: Int) -> T {
    return objects.filter{ $0.id == id }[0]
}
```

Comment: That is true but it doesn't explain the issue with an array typed as a protocol. And what if this were about a property not defined by the protocol but defined only in class A?

Comment: I will accept this answer, since it helped me resolve this particular issue for now. As @matt said though, it doesn't help with the general problem.

Comment: I agree. You're right to accept it but we're not getting anywhere with _my_ problem. :)

Comment: A personal statement: For me Swift is a language which encourages the developer to specify the types as narrow as possible and as generic as necessary rather than as generic as possible and as narrow as necessary ;-)